# ColdFusion : create a wsdl without any complex type included

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, wsdl, complextype

I have to create a wsdl webservice using ColdFusion to be used by an 'external' tool.

The problem I am facing is that this external tool doesn't accept webservices that uses complex types (the wsdl should only get and return simple values as string or integer, but no array, structure or obect).

Seems that coldfusion automatically adds some paart using complex types withing the wsdl.

My question is : Is there a way to generate a wsdl webservice in ColdFusion that wouldn't include any complex type part (and so be usable with my 'external' tool)

Thanks a lot

Comment: I've seen something similar in that Lotus Notes was not able to consume any webservice written in ColdFusion, even a simple Hello World type.  If you write a webservice that takes no arguments and returns a string, can you call it with your external tool?

Comment: nope, I've been 'prototyping' a wsdl that just contains a function that simply returns a boolean.
It Fails because Coldfusion add some functions or whaterver element using complex data to my simple dummy test function

Comment: By the way yes I tried with a webservices writtent in another technology and there is works fine. the issues comes from the fact that ColdFusion does add specific 'complex' stuff in the wsld.
I know using another language (ie java) as a wrapper is a solution. but it's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wsdlfile` attribute of the `cfcomponent` tag to use a pre-defined WSDL file instead of using the WSDL file generated by ColdFusion.

From the [Producing WSDL files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78a6.html) page:

> For complete control of the WSDL, advanced users can specify the cfcomponent wsdlFile attribute to use a predefined WSDL file.

And from the [cfcomponent documentation page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e0e.html):

> wsdlfile - Optional - A properly formatted WSDL file to be used instead of WSDL generated by ColdFusion.

Comment: Yup, I've had to do this before to allow .NET clients to consume CF web services. You can start by allowing CF to generate the WSDL, then save and modify it. The only downside to this approach is that the URL of the endpoint is in the WSDL, so you need to be careful about what kind of client is consuming it and whether or not it allows the URL to be specified via another path or whether it always reads the endpoint in the WSDL (as CF does), in which case you'll have to edit the WSDL for each deployment