# Adding annotation and documentation child elements to Coldfusion generated WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl

I am working on a ColdFusion SOAP web service and I cannot figure out how to add an annotation child element and documentation child element to the WSDL that is generated.

This is my intended output:

```
<xsd:element name="country" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>The ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    ....                                
</xsd:element>
```

My ColdFusion generated WSDL looks like this:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="country" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

I have defined the arguments in the cfcomponent > cffunction like this:

```
<cfargument name="country" type="string" required="true" default="" hint="The ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code"/>
```

Using the hint attribute does not add the annotation and documentation child elements but I cannot find another way to achieve this in the ColdFusion docs.

In searching for an answer I have seen ColdFusion SOAP web services described as "half-baked". Am I setting myself up for failure by trying this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control the WSDL that is generated by ColdFusion you can use the `wsdlfile` attribute of the `cfcomponent` tag to use a pre-defined WSDL file instead of using the WSDL file generated by ColdFusion.

From the [Producing WSDL files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78a6.html) page:

> For complete control of the WSDL, advanced users can specify the cfcomponent wsdlFile attribute to use a predefined WSDL file.

And from the [cfcomponent documentation page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e0e.html):

> wsdlfile - Optional - A properly formatted WSDL file to be used instead of WSDL generated by ColdFusion.

Most likely you will need to play around with this a bit to get the output how you want it. I posted this answer to another similar question a while back - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17174756/1636917  Notice the comment that was posted there regarding the endpoint URL needing to be within the WSDL.

Comment: Thank you, Miguel. I appreciate your pointing me in the right direction. I have taken the ColdFusion generated WSDL, saved it, added annotations, and added the `wsdlfile` attribute to the `cfcomponent` tag as you suggested.